# Using PHP to recursively find xml child tags while keeping track of parents

Tags: php, xml, recursion

first I'll preface that I'm just learning this all on the fly so I may not use the correct terminology.

Here's an extremely simplified version of the XML I need to parse:

```
 <MyXML>
    <Project>
        <ProjectName>MyProject</ProjectName>
        <ProjectType>Construction</ProjectType>
    </Project>
    <Folder>
        <folderid>0</folderid>
        <name>Root</name>
        <Depth></Depth>
        <Folder>
            <folderid>43943</folderid>
            <name>Construction Drawings</name>
            <ParentEntityID>0</ParentEntityID>
            <Folder>
                <folderid>43944</folderid>
                <name>Architectural</name>
                <ParentEntityID>43943</ParentEntityID>
                <Folder>
                    <folderid>43952</folderid>
                    <name>AutoCAD</name>
                    <ParentEntityID>43944</ParentEntityID>
                    <File>
                        <folderid>43952</folderid>
                        <filename>error.doc</filename>
                    </File>
                    <File>
                        <folderid>43952</folderid>
                        <filename>sb124a-map.jpg</filename>
                    </File>
                </Folder>
            </Folder>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <folderid>43975</folderid>
            <name>Bid Management</name>
            <ParentEntityID>0</ParentEntityID>
            <File>
                <folderid>43975</folderid>
                <filename>ION Invoice 182 2013-04-09A.pdf</filename>
            </File>
            <Folder>
                <folderid>99999</folderid>
                <name>Temp</name>
                <ParentEntityID>43975</ParentEntityID>
                <File>
                    <folderid>99999</folderid>
                    <filename>ION Invoice 182 2013-04-09B.pdf</filename>
                </File>
            </Folder>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
</MyXML>
```

As you can see there are variable levels of folders, with files scattered throughout the levels.  There is also a reference in each folder to the folderid of its parent (ParentEntityID), and each file also has a reference to its parent folder (folderid).  Not sure if that's helpful at all.

What I would want from all this is a listing of every file and its path, the projectname and project type in a csv, for example from this XML:

```
MyProject,Construction,Root/Construction Drawings/Architectural/AutoCad, error.doc
MyProject,Construction,Root/Construction Drawings/Architectural/AutoCad, sb124a-map.jpg
MyProject,Construction,Root/Bid Management,ION Invoice 182 2013-04-09A.pdf
MyProject,Construction,Root/Bid Management/Temp,ION Invoice 182 2013-04-09B.pdf
```

I can figure out how to capture the ProjectName and ProjectType as that structure is always known and static. I feel like I need some sort of recursion for the variableness of the folder/file portion, but I'm really struggling.

In the real XML which is thousands of lines long, even the File elements have child elements where I need to capture data, but I figure if I can understand how to work on this simplified XML then I should be able to figure out the rest.  I hope.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, recursion is the best method to obtain this result.

```
<?php

function indepth($path, $current_folder)
{
    global $project_name, $project_type;
    $path[] = $current_folder->name;    
    foreach ($current_folder->File as $file) {
        echo $project_name . ',' . $project_type . ',' . implode('/', $path) . ', ' . $file->filename . "\n";
    }
    foreach ($current_folder->Folder as $folder) {
        indepth($path, $folder);
    }
}

$myxml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$project_name = $myxml->Project->ProjectName;
$project_type = $myxml->Project->ProjectType;

foreach ($myxml->Folder as $folder) {
    indepth(array(), $folder);
}
```

Using `global` isn't usually a good practice, but here it permits to access to project variables inside indepth() without passing them as arguments for each recursive call.

Comment: Please bear with me. So the foreach ($myxml->Folder as $folder) will parse through every folder at the top level? with $folder containing the current 'location' in the XML? Then the indepth function looks for files at the current level, then looks for folders at the current level. When it finds one it runs the function again, looks for files, looks for more folders, drilling down.  Sounds like as well if at any particular folder level there were more elements I needed to check, I could just add more "$current_folder->elementname" to access 'local' elements. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are. $folder and $file variables are SimpleXMLElement objects. [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) allows a very easy access to each element of your XML document.